# How can I merge or join Grease Pencil objects in collection?

Tags: grease-pencil

[image: Here is the screenshot attached.]

I was working with grease pencil and I made a little character. As I was experimenting I separated the eyes and couple of more objects.

How can I now join and make them as one single object?

Thanks for your help!

W

Answer (score 1):

Select all your objects -> go to Object menu -> Join. (Or use the shortcut Ctrl + J)

Answer (score 1):

Use de Joint option with the GP objects selected.

[image]